# What is 家ーーーーー！！ supposed to mean here? [FFXIV video game slang]

Tags: meaning, slang, internet-slang

In an FFXIV music video, they got cheeky and showed a funny hypothetical chat-log during a Raid.

[image: Chat Log]

I basically understand all of it, except for the "家ーーーーー！！" exclamation in the beginning. Any idea what that is? My only guess is that maybe it's meant to be read as "イェーーーー！！" (i.e. "yay~~~~~")

Comment: You are just right. It should be *yay* that happened to be rendered into kanji.

Comment: Original video for context: https://youtu.be/BO_FIDcm2fE?si=ZqZcs1-7tLRfHWD7

Comment: It could be either a 感じミス (excuse me, 漢字ミス ;) ) or a deliberate substitution as a one-off pun.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is almost certainly correct; it's "Yeeeeah". However, unless I'm missing something known only to hardcore FFXIV fans, this is not at all an established slang word or meme. Even native speakers would need to see it in context and guess its meaning like you did.

The character's name is also "Ieeeeeee", so this might be supposed to be something this player has registered as a unique set phrase specific to this character. (Based on a quick search and [this person's profile](https://kardian.net/pages/gunn), I couldn't find any connection between him and the kanji 家.)

Comment: For the record, all the "characters" are parodies of the band members. That character is parodying "Gunn Lee" aka GUNN. But thanks!

Comment: @chausies I know, but I don't know where  "Ieeeeeee" came from. Does it have something to do with "Lee"?